# Edit mode break formatting on the Recently Viewed page

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app, recent-activity

My Recently Viewed page looks like this:

> [image: recently-normal]

After tapping on Edit button (right bottom) formatting breaks down for items where title doesn't fit in a new width:

> [image: recently-edit]

In particular:

- tags are missing
- answer icon moves on delimiter line

---

- App Version: 1.6.5.2
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)
- OS Version: Version 10.3.1 (Build 14E304)

Comment: Repro on iPhone too

Comment: @Cai yoo-hoo... not only iPad-specific bug found :)

Comment: Because the title is multi-line, there's really not a good way to do this.  I tried pinning the heights using calculations but that was difficult to get right.  I'm thinking of just having things slide right and the rightmost X pixels just get cropped, but that's probably *worse* than what's happening now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be fixed in 1.7.0. (I'm doing a version bump, it'll be the next build.)

Cells don't automatically request new heights when `tableView.isEditing` is toggled.  Now when the view controller toggles that value, it will also trigger an animated refresh of the table view, and we're storing separate height data based on the value of isEditing.

On a related note, I'm also fixing a case on iPhone where the last line of tags would get omitted if the height had a non-integral value. (26.5 -> 26 = too short)