# Incorrect plural form when posts updated

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, ios-app, plurals

When [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/295091/339911) and his answer were updated I saw the banner:

> [image: banner]

You can see that question has only one answer, but message says "answers".

- App Version: 1.6.6.2
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)
- OS Version: Version 10.3.2 (Build 14F89)

Comment: Don't be too strict. Actually it's OK to have such a small mistake.

Comment: @iBug bug is still a bug even if its priority is low. I'll continue submit bug reports like the current one.

Comment: You now have to live in fear of [Jeff Atwood's giant S](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/63791#63791).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is more or less by design.

When the question hasn't changed, we can show "N new answers", "N answers edited" or "N new and edited answers."

When the question and answers have changed, there's only so much information we can cram in there and still fit on a 320pt wide phone.

"Question and answers updated" means the question has changed and the answers *section* has changed.  This could be mean we have edited existing answers or added new ones.  In either case, the question is in a lot of flux, so refreshing is probably a good idea. ;)

Comment: For refreshing I would like to [use swipe action too](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/284941/339911).

Comment: That is too bad it is by design @alexolut now you'll have a visit [from Jeff with his Giant-S](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/63791/158100) ...

Comment: @rene welcome to the [club](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296225/plural-issue-while-cleaning-recently-viewed-posts#comment961137_296225) :)

Comment: If you know number of answers when showing a banner, why not to select appropriate plural form?